# Explore current folder command?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, shortcuts

In Windows Explorer, when navigating to a specific folder, the folders tree in the left side remains where it was at the beginning, not selecting the current folder.

Is there a shortcut or command to expand and select the currently opened folder so it shows the whole tree up to the current folder in the left side?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. In File Explorer, click the View tab, click Navigation Pane, and enable the option "Expand to open folder".